# Encode USB packets (part 2)

Tags: code-golf, binary, encoding

*Inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdgULBpRoXk) by Ben Eater. This challenge forms a pair with [Decode USB packets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/229375).*

The USB 2.0 protocol uses, at a low level, a line code called [**non-return-to-zero**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-return-to-zero) encoding (specifically, a variant called [NRZI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-return-to-zero#Non-return-to-zero_inverted)), in which a stream of bits is encoded into a stream of two electrical level states `J` and `K`. Encoding works as follows:

- Start with some initial state, which is either `J` or `K`
- For each bit to be encoded:

  - If the bit is a 0, switch the state from `J` to `K` or from `K` to `J`
  - If the bit is a 1, maintain the same state as before
  - and output that state

For this challenge, we will assume the encoding starts in state `J`.

However, it's not that simple: an additional process called [**bit stuffing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_stuffing) takes place, which is designed to make it easier to detect if the signal has dropped out. After 6 consecutive `1`s are read, an extra meaningless `0` bit is processed to ensure the signal never stays in the same state (`J` or `K`) for too long.

The full USB specification is available [here](https://usb.org/document-library/usb-20-specification) on the USB website, or mirrored (and easier to access) [here](https://eater.net/downloads/usb_20.pdf), but I'd caution you before reading it because it's extremely long and the pertinent information is hard to pin down.

### Task

Given a non-empty binary string as input, encode the string using the USB implementation of NRZI described above, and output a string of `J`s or `K`s.

### Test-cases

```
Input              Output
=====================================
1                  J
0                  K
1000101            JKJKKJJ
00000000           KJKJKJKJ
11111111           JJJJJJKKK
001111100          KJJJJJJKJ
0011111100         KJJJJJJJKJK
00111111100        KJJJJJJJKKJK
0011111111111100   KJJJJJJJKKKKKKKJKJ
0011011000111001   KJJJKKKJKJJJJKJJ
01101000011101000111010001110000011100110011101000101111001011110111011101110111011101110010111001111001011011110111010101110100011101010110001001100101001011100110001101101111011011010010111101110111011000010111010001100011011010000011111101110110001111010110010001010001011101110011010001110111001110010101011101100111010110000110001101010001   KKKJJKJKJJJJKKJKJJJJKKJKJJJJKJKJKKKKJKKKJKKKKJJKJKKJJJJJKJJKKKKKJJJJKKKKJJJJKKKKJJJJKKKKJKKJJJJKJJJJJKJJKKKJJJJJKKKKJJKKJJJJKKJKJJJJKKJJKKKJKJJKJJJKJJKKJKKJJJJKJJJKJKKKJJJKKKKKJJJKKKJJKJJKKKKKJJJJKKKKJJJKJKJJKKKKJJKJKKKJKJJJKKKJJKJKJKKKKKKKJKKKKJJJKJKKKKKJJKKKJKKJKJJKKJKJJKKKKJJJJKJJJKKJKJJJJKKKKJKKKKJKKJJKKJJJJKKKJKKKKJJKKKJKJKKKJKJJJKKJJKJKK
```

### Rules

- The input should be a string or array of `1`s and `0`s or of `true`s and `false`s
- The output should be a string or array, with the two states `J` and `K` being represented by any two distinct values
- You may use any [standard I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23457)

Comment: Should "After 6 consecutive 1 bits are *written*" be "... *read*"?

Comment: I see that we may choose what we output for `J` and `K`, but may we take an input where `0` means `true` and `1` means `false`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan 1: no - after you've written the Js or Ks corresponding to 6 consecutive 1 bits, you should pretend there's an extra 0 and encode that too. 2: I think I'm gonna say no on that.

Comment: Re (1), your explanation makes sense but "no" does not. I think something like this would be much clearer: "After 6 consecutive `1`s are read an extra, meaningless `0` bit is processed to ensure the signal never stays in the same state ( `J` or `K`) for too long." (note that it is not 6 consecutive `Ks` or `J`s being written as some examples have 7 of each in a row).

Comment: @JonathanAllan ok, changed

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

Expects a binary string. Returns an array of 0's and 1's.

```javascript
s=>[...s.replace(/1{6}/g,'$&0')].map(q=c=>q^=c^!!++q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7LDoIwEEX3fgUQo23QdmbjrvyIkaSphWiQ8jBujN@OSFGhiLe76T0n9yxvslbVqbhuc3PUTSKaWkR7xljNKl1kUmnC8b578HSzXq5gTQ/sIgtSCiWiMhYq9v0wLGmjTF6bTLPMpCQhAQbeOJR6nHu4cHrwuwduDwEAYWDtfe0RcGrtEzhWtG8i7@PU7bHVTPX9T@Do7Rln@l9g1H9NmiM@iEP8Q96ci3SZWQddwZoHoAW6idg8AQ)

#### Commented

This is a rather straightforward implementation in two steps.

```javascript
s =>           // s = input string

               // STEP 1 - Bit stuffing
               //
[...s.replace( // replace in s:
  /1{6}/g,     //   each group of six consecutive 1's
  '$&0'        //   with the same group with a trailing 0
)]             // split the resulting string

               // STEP 2 - NRZI encoding
               //
.map(q =       // initialize q to a zero'ish, non-numeric value
  c =>         // for each character c:
  q ^=         //   invert q if ...
    c ^        //     ... c is not equal to the result of
    !!++q      //     the test 'q is a number'
               //     (0 on the 1st iteration, 1 afterwards)
)              // end of map()
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
G=Jḋ126xḋ63
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qGGBRrK2ucmhNZq5j5oa/7vbej3c0W1oZFYBpMyM////Hx1tGKsTbQDEhjoGYAiiwWI6KBCsAgVC1SBEIKpQxXCJQsRjAQ)

Input as array of `0`s and `1`s, output as array of `1`s (for state `J`) and `0`s (for state `K`): TIO header converts to `J`s and `K`s.

```
       x    # split input on
        ḋ63 # binary digits of 63 = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
  J         # then join back together using
   ḋ126     # binary digits of 126 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
G=          # and scan from the left by equality
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
7Ṭ¬©Ṗœṣ@j®⁼\
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of integers (from \$[0,1]\$) and yields a list of integers (from \$[0,1]\$) where \$0\$ represents \$K\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/84c41h9YcWvlw57Sjkx/uXOyQdWjdo8Y9Mf///4820FEAIkMiEEhlLAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/84c41h9YcWvlw57Sjkx/uXOyQdWjdo8Y9Mf8f7t5yaGvYo6Y1h9sf7u5@1LjPy1vHQdMbKBD5/78hlwGXoYGBgaEBkAUFXIZQABQB00AhKAuZicJGFgAhsIQByFAQ3wDKN0SjDeDqDJEkDCBmQWlc2ABGwTlI6g0M0eyDOQpqlQGyfgOYo6H6oU7GsN8A5jiouQh9MI@gqDWE2gw2CmqnAbL7kdwH878BktvhQQK1GWYfRBcA).

#### How?

```
7Ṭ¬©Ṗœṣ@j®⁼\ - Link: list of integers in [0..1], A
7            - seven
 Ṭ           - untruth -> [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
  ¬          - logical NOT -> [1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
   ©         - copy to register
    Ṗ        - pop -> [1,1,1,1,1,1]
     œṣ@     - (A) split on sublists equal to (that)
         ®   - recall from register
        j    - (split list) join (register value)
           \ - cumulative reduce with:
          ⁼  -   (left) equals (right)?
```

---

11 if we could take input with `0` meaning *true* and `1` meaning *false* with `7Ṭ©Ṗœṣ@j®⁻\`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
“?~‘Bœṣjƭƒ^¬¥\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rwxz7ukcNM5yOTn64c3HWsbXHJsUdWnNoacz/sEdNaw63P9zd/ahxn5f3//9KBoaGBoYGQGAIZSDTMHEDCIZKgFiGcBoXNoBRcA6SegNDNPvA8iBlBlDVSPrBipD0Q52MYb8BzHFQcxH6YB5BUWsItRlsFNROA2T3I7kP5n8DJLfDgwRqM8w@iC4lAA)

-2 bytes thanks to Nick Kennedy

```
“?~‘Bœṣjƭƒ^¬¥\  Main Link; accepts a list of [0, 1] on the left
“?~‘            63, 126
    B           To binary ([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
         ƒ      Reduce starting with the input:
        ƭ       Tie; cycle
     œṣ         The first time, split on sublist ([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
       j        The second time, join on [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
             \  Cumulative reduce
          ^¬¥   Each time, XOR, and then logical NOT
```

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rwxz7ukcNM5yOTn64c3HWsbXHJsUdWnNoacz/sEdNaw63P9zd/ahxn5f3//9KBoaGBoYGQGAIZSDTMHEDCIZKgFiGcBoXNoBRcA6SegNDNPvA8iBlBlDVSPrBipD0Q52MYb8BzHFQcxH6YB5BUWsItRlsFNROA2T3I7kP5n8DJLfDgwRqM8w@iC4lAA)

Comment: @NickKennedy ah I keep forgetting hooked `f`. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 31 bytes

Outputs `KJ` as `01`.

```
v|6
0"("=0
+*6!<}
""~,="
{ 5 1<
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoidnw2XG4wXCIoXCI9MFxuKyo2ITx9XG5cIlwifiw9XCJcbnsgNSAxPCIsInYiOjEsImkiOiIwIDAgMSAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMCAwIn0=)

In the top left is a counter that gets incremented by the input 1s `+` and reset whenever it reaches 6 `|6` or the input has a 0 `*`. If it reaches 6, it also injects a 0 into the stream (the `("=0 6!<` part). Because the input stream would be faster (the 0 would get there 2 bits too late), we delay it by 5 ticks `~5`. On the bottom right is the current output bit that gets flipped on 0s with `=` and then copied into the output `=}`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 59 bytes

```r
function(x)cumsum(49-utf8ToInt(gsub('(1{6})','\\10',x)))%%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLLasMwELznKwIlSIIUZksp7aEf0HuPgULcpPQQG2oLAqXf7sbW7mqlOA5BsTSvHeVnjP3@49A23efhdTzGthm@u9afQxNPfTz5x5f7OByf37u3dvBffdx75@n36S@4rdvtCG57DiFsNg9GxztyYX23rh@sLAaLGCowBIBQq01bl5NSjZ8SSkifUpSfEprol@1KdoZWusRgLGErMGOnGIvoEq7om/CCk@FpeyHRXBVmDmVSAs@xKooe8A@7QpXIHCAl4vXWF7Loi8GDKj@JzVawfMhYzOfIV/6QcKybeaazjOUCkx97wuY3@WR@mOxaCTuLX2Jx9ToNTNFyE@UE0hKkBxLhhVWmzWBkDNV@UkquOPN5OvXjIFf@hOIyzZ9EBslzyIa0B61TRYuA5m41vHZCVN3q9LYa/wE)

Regex-based bit-stuffing <s>stolen from</s> inspired by [pajonk's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229384/95126) to the  paired usb-decoding challenge.

The state-switching is achieved here by determining whether the cumulative sum is odd or even.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
\16*:0+V1$(nɽß¬…
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C16*%3A0%2BV1%24%28n%C9%BD%C3%9F%C2%AC%E2%80%A6&inputs=%2711111111%27&header=&footer=)

```
\16*             # Six ones
    :0+          # Duplicate and append a 0
       V         # Replace in input
        1$       # Starting with a one
          (      # Iterating through the string
             ß¬  # Flip if...
           nɽ    # It's a 1
               … # Print without popping
```

Returns 1 for J and 0 for K. [Here](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C16*%3A0%2BV1%24%28n%C9%BD%C3%9F%C2%AC%3A%60KJ%60%24i%E2%82%B4&inputs=%2711111111%27&header=&footer=)'s a version that does JKs.

Answer (score 3):

### [<>^v](https://github.com/Astroide/---v#v), 161 bytes

```
1±n"0"o"1"i0q.h"J"j"K"kJtv
v   v=ICc®NHn)N  v=N-?1¿H<
    >Q)7=v_qv    >`!     ~
 vcOn(Nq0<  v    >Ktv    T
v<          <>TJ=^Jtv    ^
>C         O=^      >    ^
```

##### Explanation

###### First line

```
1±n"0"o"1"i0q.h"J"j"K"kJtv

1                          Push 1 to stack
 ±                         Negate
  n                        Store in variable `n`
   "0"                     Push "0"
      o                    Store in variable `o`
       "1"                 Push "1"
          i                Store in variable `i`
           0               Push 0
            q              Store in variable `q`
             .             Read line from stdin
              h            Store in variable `h`
               "J"         Push "J"
                  j        Store in variable `j`
                   "K"     Push "K"
                      k    Store in variable `k`
                       J   Push value of variable `j` ("J")
                        t  Store in variable `t`
                         v Redirect instruction pointer down
```

The variables `i` and `o` store the values `"1"` and `"0"`", `j` and `k` store `"J"` and `"K"`. `h` contains the line read from stdin (1's and 0's). `q`, initialized to 0, will be used for bit stuffing. `n` is the "current character pointer".

###### The main loop

```
v   v=ICc®NHn)N  v=N-?1¿H< <-- loop starts here
    >Q)7=v_qv    >`!     ~
 vcOn(Nq0<  v    >Ktv    T
v<          <>TJ=^Jtv    ^
>C         O=^      >    ^
[start of loop]
<    Send instruction pointer leftward
H    Push value of variable `h` to stack
¿    Push length of top of stack
1    Push 1
?    Swap top two elements
-    Substract second element of stack to top of stack
N    Push value of variable `n`
=    If the top two elements of the stack (length of `h` - 1 and `n`) are equal (reached end of string)
    v    Send instruction pointer down
    >    Send instruction pointer right 
    `    Print newline
    !    Exit
N    Push value of variable `n` (character index in string)
)    Increment top of stack (increment character index in string)
n    Pop and write to variable `n`
H    Push value of variable `h` (string that was previously read from stdin and that contains the 0's and 1's
N    Push value of variable `n`
®    Set top of stack to (second element of stack)[top of stack] (character read)
c    Write to variable `c` ("current")
C    Push value of variable `c` (variable write pops the stack)
I    Push value of variable `i` ("1")
=    If the top two elements of the stack (current character and "1") are equal
    v    Send instruction pointer down
    >    Send instruction pointer right
    Q    Push value of variable `q`
    )    Increment top of stack
    7    Push 7
    =    If the top two elements of the stack are equal (`q` and 7)
        v    Send the instruction pointer down
        <    Send the instruction pointer left
        0    Push 0
        q    Pop stack and write to variable `q`
        N    Push value of variable `n`
        (    Decrement top of stack
        n    Pop stack and write to variable `n`
        O    Push value of variable `o` ("0")
        c    Pop stack and write to variable `c` (current character)
        v    Send instruction pointer down
        <    Send instruction pointer left
        Go to [loop-continuation]
    Else
    _    Pop stack (remove the 7)
    q    Pop stack and write to variable `q`
    v    Send instruction pointer down
    v    Same as previous, only for readability
    <    Send instruction pointer left
    <    Same
    Go to [loop-continuation]
[loop-continuation]
Else
v.   Send instruction pointer down
v.   Same
>.   Send instruction pointer right
C.   Push value of variable `c` to stack (current character)
O.   Push value of variable `O` ("0")
=.   If the top two elements of the stack (current character and "0") are equal
    ^    Send instruction pointer up
    >.   Send instruction pointer right
    T.   Push to stack value of variable `t` (current state, J or K)
    J.   Push to stack value of variable `j` ("J")
    =    If the top two elements of the stack (current state and "J" are equal)
        ^.   Send instruction pointer up
        >.   Send instruction pointer left
        K.   Push value of variable `k` ("K")
        t.   Pop stack and write to variable `t`
        v.   Send instruction pointer down
        Continue at the [here] indicator
    Else
    J    Push value of variable `j` ("J")
    t.   Pop stack and write to variable `t`
    v.   Send instruction pointer down
    Continue at the [here] indicator
[here]
>.   Send instruction pointer right
^.   Send instruction pointer up
^.   Same
T.   Push value of variable `t` ("J" or "K")
~.   Print top of stack without newline
Go to [start of loop] indicator
```

That can be clarified to :

```
while has not reached end of string:
    increment character_index
    current_character = string[character_index]
    if current_character is a 1:
        increment one_count
        if one_count is 7:
            set one_count to zero
            decrement character_index
            current_character = 0
    if current_character is a 0:
        if state is J:
            state = K
        else:
            state = J
    print state
print newline
exit
```

[run online - largest input](https://v.astroide.repl.co/?i=MDExMDEwMDAwMTExMDEwMDAxMTEwMTAwMDExMTAwMDAwMTExMDAxMTAwMTExMDEwMDAxMDExMTEwMDEwMTExMTAxMTEwMTExMDExMTAxMTEwMTExMDExMTAwMTAxMTEwMDExMTEwMDEwMTEwMTExMTAxMTEwMTAxMDExMTAxMDAwMTExMDEwMTAxMTAwMDEwMDExMDAxMDEwMDEwMTExMDAxMTAwMDExMDExMDExMTEwMTEwMTEwMTAwMTAxMTExMDExMTAxMTEwMTEwMDAwMTAxMTEwMTAwMDExMDAwMTEwMTEwMTAwMDAwMTExMTExMDExMTAxMTAwMDExMTEwMTAxMTAwMTAwMDEwMTAwMDEwMTExMDExMTAwMTEwMTAwMDExMTAxMTEwMDExMTAwMTAxMDEwMTExMDExMDAxMTEwMTAxMTAwMDAxMTAwMDExMDEwMTAwMDE=#d2946ddce572d88f5079f600c5b12fbd5f667238f1b0271ab0e5f49b098e6a9f)

[run online - enter input yourself](https://v.astroide.repl.co/#d2946ddce572d88f5079f600c5b12fbd5f667238f1b0271ab0e5f49b098e6a9f)

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 79 bytes

```
func[x][p: 0 x: replace/all x"111111""1111110"forall x[prin p: 49 - x/1 xor p]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBCsMgDIbvfYqQ@2iEXda9gd52FQ@lVTYobZENfHunsay27FfI4f/@hMTbMT7sqE3juug@86CD0WsHBKEDb9epH2zbTxMEFCzcKqFbPBt69a8ZUuZ6gwuEVkBYPKzGxETYfnjCG3SDAuGsO0pskP4ZKhmCiAQdcimhpFKSc5vwkJPl5fimgy9ZSiluUDapOuQGhZA7UBM/IE@pkIqpkBOzgzXD2gfmzwni1QtZCJ6aOKNdumk@@xsQTfwC)

Both input and output are strings of \$1\$s and \$0\$s. Output is done by printing.
Despite the unwieldy string replacement, other ways to account for the extra zero bit tend to be even longer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
1{6}
$&0
{+rT`d`JK`K.
1T`d`KJ`\d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVC7DsIwDNz9HVAhIaHzwi8gNSsjQ5DK0IWhYqv49pCk5@AWESXy@XnnTI/X@Lyn/eESk87nt@w6yHycrnGIfYjhJFpg6ONtSEkFogAUGfGI8uRItTlE5OEK@0C5NYEytPigrxuLVqcugWUW7b8HM81x9dANn4kiFXw/TDT7KfmHHyaOc799tsiqVslcR5ETXr/TZ/vDaW9fQmbjW7o@) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
1{6}
$&0
```

Perform bit-stuffing.

```
{`
```

Make as many replacements as possible.

```
+rT`d`JK`K.
```

Change `0` after a `K` to `J` and `1` after a `K` to `K`. Change starting with the character after the last `K` (and working back, not that it matters), and keep replacing characters until there are no digits after a `K`.

```
1T`d`KJ`\d
```

The first remaining digit is not after a `K`, so change `0` to `K` and `1` to `J`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
≔⪫⪪Ｓ×1⁶⁺×1⁶0θ⭆θ§JK№…θ⊕κ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYyxCoMwGIT3PkXI9AdSiEsXJ8kUpSDYF5AYNDT@URNL@/Rp2lJob7u7705P/aZ971KqQrAjQu0tQrc4G0HhsscubhZHYJxc7GwC0IJycmLZt24P8BdyQgV9VSsrD23eRfjMz/0CKydVVDiYO9C6ybz0ewbkQzsjJ/8GFOrNzAajGeDKvn@MlSkJUfxIiHS8uSc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪫⪪Ｓ×1⁶⁺×1⁶0θ
```

Perform bit-stuffing.

```
⭆θ§JK№…θ⊕κ0
```

For each prefix of the string count the number of `0`s and output `K` if it is odd and `J` if it is even.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 21 bytes

```
0=\.'(t,$0)/(t:6#$1)\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJx1UjGOwzAM2/2Kg1qgCRD05KVDDgfcbH6hc6eOnfv21hblqA7OSSDYIkVKzm3V3+v5ND2Wo87f02O9HI55vqZ0X6VAflKaFikyP+9ft79FstQ9+l4lvWEFKEXqkWRVzfqGCYo9dq5cFd8WADK4GsVSndMSjcRUrfiRHLK79Jhva1QYoQZpagFY30ZQ66827bgxtpkAhZ8hwQ7MhvvZRbh0B5cNg1HPzcLRgQ+SXY9GdvrwQ6cEMLahdbBbAY0gFKByNwhsXXXREioEQSvOideBKweeh6j9InJIqF0i43+feuibgNc86PmtU0ojX/2vIJ+Wd/rq5lh343kjH9hM5VaKmpqD/+DP+9fgvY+Eyq5nLEkvFPXv7w==)

Takes input as a string of `"1"`s and `"0"`s. Returns a list of `0`s (for `J`) and `1`s (for `K`).

- do a string replace of `"111111"` with `"1111110"`

  - `(t:6#$1)` store `"111111"` in variable `t`
  - `(t,$0)` append a `"0"` to the end of `t`, generating `"1111110"`
- `.'` convert each character to an integer
- `0=\` use a equals-scan, seeded with 0 (this does the non-return-to-zero part)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>84</s> <s>80</s> 78 bytes

-6 thanks to @ceilingcat

```c
x;c;a(char*p){for(c=0,x=1;*p;c>5&&a(L"10"+x))putchar(x^=*p<49),c=*p++/49*-~c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLvaoMwEP/uU0hgRa1lF9g@FNc9QG6PUAYS1s0PS6W1IJTu1V2T3Gma2lS5mP7@JTm9@tZ6GPpKV3Wmf@pD0ebn3f6Q6Q2U/UZWRVvp99fFos4@hASx7PO8PXUWmfWfm6J9e1nnpb5Olsvnl3Wx@tPVZWhMl3Zfx84rpo0pUz/bn7o8OSfpddRZY/LKTdvDlbDLxNY8Hbdma0RpcVVySRKr9Fs3JmOakxVSlKlQgvh@Dewa3q5JAJDg0agQVcyh4ajK/yIFGk7CDUSMRRyCVTxIzWJuQdZuHhbjHgNn0W7MZrCP44I/FfR4hT5OzLAEIIKMKoxCMvgDfB6qj17gMn4EeJCRH6cmKwj5wLsiPkW@8wcOR7oTjzdyg5Xk7KTIE8L8QT7ePwTZxyMhZ/bzLHfythv54OPqmhVR0euRSD3jL5hv@q4i3@UIVhMGYz@@fWR0wEcisx8FufNHXmRKAMapHUcwR0EKgoEAOY8BEaddjaYqUAgMvbht4cvwDw)  Takes input as the characters `0` and `1`, outputs with bytes `0x01` for `J` and `0x00` for `K`.

For output as actual `J` and `K`,
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLvasIwEP/epyiBSVsru4AypHMPkNsjyKCE6fphtWiFgrhX70xy18ZYT8vV@PuX5PRir3Xfd4UuykT/lMesSS@7wzHRG8i7jSyyptAfq9msTD6FBDHv0rT72mTN@3Kd61ufz1@X62zxp/Pm3BqB5G216NLi2ld1G7ffp9bJxlWdx@7tcG7T6BLFtyqTqk4L@9ocb4RdIrb1y2lbb2uRG1wRXaPIKP2WVZ0wzcoKKfJYKEF8twZmDe/XJABIcGhUiCrkUFmqcp9AgcpK2ELEUMQiWMWB1CTmHmTspmEh7jlwEm1rMoP5Wi64U0GHV@jihAxDACLIoMMgJL0/wOWh/uwBbsMPDw8y8OPUZAU@H3hXxKfID/7A4Uh35PFG7rCSnK0UeYKf38vH@wcv@3Ak5Mx@jmVP3kwjH3zY7bAiKnocEmlm3AXzTT905LscwGrEYOjHt4@M9vhIZPajIA/@yItM8cA4juMA5ihIQdATIOchIOK4q8FUeQqeoRM3I3zt/wE)

[Decoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229553/80050)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 85 bytes

```hs
map("JK"!!).(0%)
j%(1:1:1:1:1:1:y)=j:j:j:j:j:j:j%(0:y)
j%(i:y)|k<-i^j*j^i=k:k%y
j%e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHbboMwDH3nK9JoqDCplfOKlh@If2GqhDrYuLRDZS@V9u1juTjgwpYInBwf@9jxRzl2Vd9PtX6dLuWQSYNyt8uPGaR50qaZKpZ9z3VbsJ1mYDHHaqz97l4Ozal9bk@N7oouvVtHpatpKG9jJfZqL7RQCd3A3SCpnanFUVhp4V3JpWyuFnz7TIQYbs31SzwJS5NKCq2FNHKFQ8BxjSsAUBCj0CCaTayiRSS/EDepQNlE4PLRgduIQ/jI4U5qtv99EM18YXxQKz3vdzQgNov3JBZPJW/0IRZHeZe42MgDV5GyT0WawOtn9cX@gdU@PwkpR70QRZNzk7HzCY@/sn5w6H/hQJP0Po8Q/w9LR0Y2CwfXekEi8IN/iUcKjnpUyEYfIxhDGDnUv/QRARLGKMqaeCgQcelqFjUsAxMMyeX0c6778n2cDudh@AU)